# Distances in general relativity

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, distance

Three dimensional distance doesn't exist in general relativity because the integration of $ d \vec l $ depends on the integration path. Well, maybe there is no mininum but it must be a maximum lower bound. Why can't we define the threedimensional distance this way?

Comment: Three dimensional distance exists all you want, just as having 3 dimensions does not prevent one from having distances of curves in a plane. Typically one will have an induced metric on the lower dimensional subspace, given by what is known as the pullback of the metric.

Comment: If you do not assign a 3D spacelike submanifold where to compute the variations you say (and there are infinite choices), the infimum is always 0.

Comment: And what is special about a space + ---- versus, for example, a 2D ++ variety in a three-dimensional space And what is special about a space + ---- versus, for example, a 2D ++ or 3D +++  variety in a three-dimensional space (say a spherical surface within Euclidean R ^ 2, or R^3 in Minkowskian space) where obviously the distances on the spherical surface aren´t they 0?

Comment: @ValterMoretti: That should be an answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not assign a 3D spacelike submanifold where to compute the variations you say (and there are infinite inequivalent choices), the infimum is always $0$. In fact, you can always continuously deform every given spacelike curve joining two spacelike related points  to a light-like curve. This fact implies that the spatial distance between two spacelike related events has no non-ambiguous meaning. To define it,  you have to choose a spacelike 3-surface containing the points and to take the infimum of the length of the curves joining the points an belonging to the 3-surface (referring to the metric induced from that of the spacetime). This notion of distance, though depending on a arbitrary choice, will satisfy all requirements of a distance function as the triangular inequality and all that.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that for time-orientable spacetimes, any lightlike curve to which you can continuously deform a spacelike curve must necessarily change time orientation?

Comment: I think so, but I do not have a rigorous proof.

Answer (score -1):

The distance is already observer dependend in special relativity, for an observer flying from $\rm A$ to $\rm B$ the distance between $\rm A$ and $\rm B$ is also shorter than for an observer at rest relative to $\rm A$ and $\rm B$ because of regular length contraction. In general relativity we have the same situation: if we take an observer freely falling from infinity (meaning with the negative escape velocity) into a Schwarzschild black hole and let him measure the distance from the horizon to the singularity, he finds the distance to be $d=2$ (in natural units of $\rm GM/c^2$):

**Approach 1: [Droste coordinates](http://yukterez.net/f/einstein.equations/files/2.html)**

The radial component of the metric is $g_{rr}=-1/(1-2/r)$, and the escape velocity $v=\sqrt{2/r}$, with the gamma factor $\gamma=1/\sqrt{1-v^2}$. The distance our free faller measures between the singularity is therefore

$$d=\int_2^0 \frac{\sqrt{-g_{rr}}}{\gamma } \, {\rm d}r = 2$$

**Approach 2: [Raindrop coordinates](http://yukterez.net/f/einstein.equations/files/raindrop.html)**

In raindrop coordinates we are already measuring the distances in the frame of our infalling observer, which gives us a velocity of $v=0$ and $\gamma=1$. The radial component of the metric tensor in this coordinates is simply $g_{rr}=-1$, so we again get

$$d=\int_2^0 \frac{\sqrt{-g_{rr}}}{\gamma } \, {\rm d}r = 2$$

If you start free fall from rest at an infinitesimal distance above the horizon, the numerically integrated distance in your frame appoaches $d=\pi$. On the other hand, if you try to calculate the distance in the frame of a stationary far away observer you get $d=-i \pi$, which is unphysical for the reason that there can't be any stationary observers between the horizon and the singularity. But if you transform into a physically meaningful frame of reference, it is no problem to calculate distances. The caveat that times and distances are relative are not a thing that only happens in general relativity, the same already happens in special relativity with the only difference that the metric tensor is Minkowski.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have very much to do with the question. The question isn't asking about the Schwarzschild spacetime.

Comment: The Schwarzschild spacetime is just the easiest example for general relativity, if you want to use the Kerr Newman De Sitter metric or something more complicated than Schwarzschild just plug the g_rr or corresponding g_xx component of your desired metric into the equations above.